# Options elements dynamically created by Knockout.js options binding does not have offsetTop value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am working on a existing add in which we are using `Knockout.js` for data binding.
One of the new requirements is to be able to automatically scroll to a specific option (determine prior by a given criteria) in the `<select>` list when you cick on the button to show the dropdown

Generally if you have hardcoded `<select>` list with `<options>` this is pretty easy to achieve by using the `scrollIntoView()` function.
The problem for me is that I noticed that all the `<option>` elements created with `Knockout options binding has`offsetTop`property of 0.
Therefore`scrollIntoView()` always scroll to the top of the list.

I am wondering if there is any solution - either to manage to assign `offsetTop` values to the `<option>` element or some other way to scroll to specific option in the list.
I can not share the exact code , so I am giving some pseudo code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <p style="margin-top: 100px;">
        Your country:
        <select id="select2" data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                       optionsText: 'countryName',
                       value: selectedCountry,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
    </p>

    <div data-bind="visible: selectedCountry"> <!-- Appears when you select something -->
        You have chosen a country with population
        <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry() ? selectedCountry().countryPopulation : 'unknown'"></span>.
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var Country = function (name, population) {
    this.countryName = name;
    this.countryPopulation = population;
};

var viewModel = {
    availableCountries: ko.observableArray([
        new Country("UK", 65000000),
        new Country("USA", 320000000),
        new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
    ]),
    selectedCountry: ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
};
$(document).ready(
$('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#select2').val("USA")[0].scrollIntoView();
    });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

**After a lot of testing and trying different things, it turns out that the problem is not in the options binding of Knockout.js but rather the  element itself. So it turns out if the  element has the size attribute set to 1 (how it is in my current case), all the  elements offset() properties are 0. 
If I change the size of the  to 2 for example (e.g. see more than one line of the dropdown menu), all the  elements come with respective values for the offset().
Any idea why is that and any workarounds? 
Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. If someone is selecting an option from the list, wouldn't it already be scrolled into view? Otherwise you cannot select it.

You could write a custom binding handler and attach it to each option, compare it with the selected option, and scroll the option element into view if they're the same.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['optionScrollIntoView'] = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var ownVal = allBindings.get('value');
        var optVal = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());        

        if (!optVal) {
            return;
        }

        if (ownVal === optVal) {
            element.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
};

var Country = function (name, population) {
    this.countryName = name;
    this.countryPopulation = population;
};

function ViewModel() {
    this.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([
        new Country("UK", 65000000),
        new Country("USA", 320000000),
        new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
    ]);
    this.selectedCountry = ko.observable();
}
```

You'd have to create the option elements yourself though:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedCountry">
    <option value="">Select a country:</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: availableCountries -->
    <option data-bind="value: $data, text: $data.countryName, optionScrollIntoView: $parent.selectedCountry"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/4Lvmoewn/23/

Comment: Maybe I didn`t explain myself properly. Imagine you have a very long lidt in the dropdown, sy 150 entries or more.The requirement that needs to be implemented is that when you click on the dropdown button and the list with options is displayed, automatically to scroll to a specific option (determine prior by other criterias) down the list.

Comment: As I said, it is very easy to be done with a static, hardcoded <option> elements, because they have the offsetTop value, but when the list of <option> is created dynamically via Knockout.js, all the elements have offsetTop value of 0. Therefore I can not navigate down using scrollIntoView()